# React router layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

У меня есть роутинг через react-router-redux:

index.j:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from "react-router-redux";
import { hashHistory } from "react-router"
import combineReducers from "./reducer";
import Root from './components/Root'


const store = createStore(combineReducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store)


ReactDOM.render(<Root history={history} store={store} />, document.getElementById('root'))

registerServiceWorker();
```

root.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import CustomersList from "./customers/CustomersList";
import CustomerCreate from "./customers/CustomerCreate";

const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/brokers/customers/list/:type/:project/:active" component={CustomersList} />
                <Route path="/brokers/customers/create" component={CustomerCreate} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    </div>
)

Root.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Root
```

сейчас в каждый компонент я вставляю компонент Header, по сути одинаковый для всех. Как его вынести за пределы компонентов? Сейчас если вставить его в   то просто компоненты не подгружаются, а если за пределы  то не доступен store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Root = ({ store, history }) => (
    <div>
    <Provider store={store} history={history}>
        <Router>
            <Layout store={store} history={history}>
                <Route path="/brokers/customers/list/:type/:project/:active" component={CustomersList} />
                <Route path="/brokers/customers/create" component={CustomerCreate} />
                <Route path="/brokers/customers/log/:id" component={LogByCustomer} />

                <Route path="/auth/login" component={Login} />
            </Layout>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    </div>
)

class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Header store={this.props.store} history={this.props.history} />
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавляйте ваши общие компоненты между `<Router>` и `<Switch>`.

Comment: так тоже нельзя. выдает ошибку A <Router> may have only one child element

Comment: А какой версии у вас роутер? 3-й или 4-й?

Comment: версия 3.2.0. я специально понизил потому что что то не работало в 4

Comment: Используйте актуальные версии пакетов. 4-й роутер не имеет обратной совместимости с третьим, его возможности также значительно шире, чем у третьего. Например, вы можете использовать роуты в любых компонентах одновременно, не только в главном контейнере, и т.д. А главное, никто не гарантирует, что старый роутер будет совместим с 15-м или 16-м реактом. Пока не наступил острый момент в разработке лучше актуализировать ваши пакеты.

Comment: В версии 4.2.0 та же ошибка, если поместить общие компоненты между <Router> и <Switch>, а вне роутера не работают ссыллки, ошибка You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Comment: 4 версия вообще не рабочая, в ней нет history

Comment: для 4-го роутера надо history загружать отдельным пакетом https://www.npmjs.com/package/history, советую почитать доку по роутеру, там неплохо написано про его установку

Answer (score -1):

В реакте каждый компонент получает свойство `children`. Соотвественно, можете написать компонент Layout, который выводить все ваши хедеры, футеры и тд, и далее поместить рутер вовнутрь так:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) = (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <main>{children}</main>
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Layout>
     <Route .... />
     <Route .... />
    </Layout>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

П.С. Комментарии выше это какое то месиво. Вовсе не надо даунгрейдить реакт-рутер

Comment: Ну допустим оберну я его в новый компонент, хотя пример и нерабочий, но как передать туда  history и store?

Comment: ну кажется вы уже разобрались :)

Comment: хистори приходит через withRouter, стор через connect - обе функции являются обертками для контейнеров. компоненты должны быть тупыми

Comment: если выложите на гитхаб или codesandbox проект, я бы глянул, может что смогу посоветовать